# somehow get notified when a pod has a new version

Tags: cocoapods

I'm using Pods in different iOS projects, now I would like to somehow get notified when a new version is released for one of the pods - no matter if via mail, rss feed or whatever. Does such a possibility exist?

Answer (score 2):

A Podfile will generally semantically constrain the allowed versions of a pod (see [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/)):

```
pod 'Bolts', '~> 1.7'
```

This example would accept versions from 1.7 up to 2.0 excluded.

So the only way to know if there is a new version that fits your project is to run specifically for your repo:

```
pod outdated
```

Knowing that, you can script a Jenkins job to check it periodically.

Comment: I do know this, but it would be great if I could somehow get a notification when e.g. a new version of `Bolts` is released, no matter if it's from `1.7` to `1.7.1` or to `2.0`...

Answer (score -1):

Try https://www.versioneye.com/ . Not sure how well it works though.